# Rendering conditionally in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to render two completely separate components based on whether the user is logged in or not.
This is my code,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ContainerLogged from './components/logged/ContainerLogged'
import ContainerUnlogged from './components/unlogged/ContainerUnlogged'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {isLoggedIn : false}
    }
    render(){
        const comp = this.state.isLoggedIn ? (
            <ContainerLogged />
        ): (
            <ContainerUnlogged />
        );
        return (

            {comp}
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

This is my index.js

```
import 'normalize.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I get the following error,

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {comp}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in App (at index.js:8)
```

I'm new to React and thus dont understand what's going on over here.

Comment: comp itself is a react child, simply return that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
return (

    {comp}
);
```

try

```
return comp;
```

Answer (score 1):

`{comp}` is an object with key `comp` and value the value of the variable `comp`. That does make much sense here. (That's ES2015 "Shorthand property names" feature)

You must simply return comp instead of an object: `return comp`

Answer (score 1):

You are in right direction, I would suggest to break your render function, it always helps when you have conditional logic.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false
    };
  }

  renderLoggedIn = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Logged In</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
  renderNotLoggedIn = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Not Logged In</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    let element = null;
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
      element = this.renderLoggedIn();
    } else {
      element = this.renderNotLoggedIn();
    }
    return element;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```